# Exception occurs ONLY with debugger in vscode

Tags: javascript, unhandled-exception, uncaught-exception

I have two(2) codes that do the same thing, BUT one of them (Code01) shows an uncaught exception when it is run with debugger in vscode, and the other one not (Code02).

Can somebody help me to understand the difference?

```
// ./vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest01.js

// "Code01" - This code has an uncaught exception.
"use strict";

async function thisThrows() {
  throw new Error("Thrown from thisThrows()"); // uncaught exception here
}

async function myFunctionThatCatches() {
  return await thisThrows().catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  });
}

async function run() {

  await myFunctionThatCatches().catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  });
}

run()
.catch( e => {
    console.error(e);
    console.error("++++ ERROR was caught");
})
```

```
// ./vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest02.js

// "Code02" - This code runs well. All exception are handled.
"use strict";

async function thisThrows() {
  throw new Error("Thrown from thisThrows()");
}

async function myFunctionThatCatches() {
  return await thisThrows().catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  });
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await myFunctionThatCatches().catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

run()
.catch( e => {
    console.error(e);
    console.error("++++ ERROR was caught");
})
```

This is the "Code02" vscode debugger output:

> Exception has occurred: Error: Thrown from thisThrows()   at
> thisThrows
> (d:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS01\libJS\LoProbe\vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest01.js:7:9)
> at myFunctionThatCatches (d:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS01\libJS\LoProbe\vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest01.js:11:16)
> at run (d:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS01\libJS\LoProbe\vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest01.js:18:9)
> at Object. (d:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS01\libJS\LoProbe\vscodeDebuggerAsyncCatchExceptionTest01.js:23:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: If you run "code01" without the debugger, do you get an exception? You're comparing two different sets of code under different conditions.

Comment: Hi, I am in agreement with you. When I run both codes without debugger, everything looks ok. BUT, when I run both codes with debugger, "Code02" behavior cannot be reproduced. It looks like that "Code02" is failing silence. This i the issue I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I found the problem in "Code01".
The problem in "Code01" was that the chain of uncaught exceptions was broken from exception on "thisThrows()" up to call to "run()" function.

Since all functions are "asynchronous" (async), the code has to WAIT until "**throwing Error**" execution is completed in "thisThrows()" function, by adding an "await" keyword.

Following is "Code04" were the problem was solved.
Lines that start with /*A*/ indicates the corrected lines of code to solve the problem in "Code01".

```
"use strict";

      async function thisThrows() {
/*A*/   throw await new Error("Thrown from thisThrows()");
        // "await" keyword was included in above line of code.
      }

      async function myFunctionThatCatches() {
          return await thisThrows().catch((e) => {
            throw e;
          });
      }

      async function run() {

          await myFunctionThatCatches().catch((e) => {
            throw e;
          });
      }

      run()
/*A*/ .then( r => console.log( "!!!! Exution was completed successfully") )
      .catch( e => {
          console.error(e);
          console.error("++++ ERROR was caught");
      })
```